# Protocol functions return a result faster if the constant it returns isn't cached

Tags: clojure, benchmarking

I'm writing an [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). Part of it is a protocol that defines how `Systems` are used. Part of the protocol is a function that returns the components that the system requires to function. It can be distilled down to the following:

```
(defprotocol System
  (required-components [sys]
    "Returns a map of keys and initial values of components that the System requires to operate.")
```

Because the value that this function returns is really a constant, I thought that caching it would probably be a good idea because it might be required +60 times a second. To tell whether or not it makes a difference though, I wrote up the following test:

```
(defrecord Input-System1 []
  System
  (required-components [sys] {:position [0 0] :angle 0}))

(def req-comps
  {:position [0 0] :angle 0})

(defrecord Input-System2 []
  System
  (required-components [sys] req-comps))
```

Then in a REPL, I ran the following time tests:

```
(let [sys (->Input-System1)]
  (time-multiple 1000000000
    (required-components sys)))

(let [sys (->Input-System2)]
  (time-multiple 1000000000
    (required-components sys)))
```

(Code for `time-multiple` below).

The odd thing is, `Input-System1` consistently finishes faster than `Input-System2`: 2789.973066ms vs 3800.345803ms on the last run.

I find this odd though given how, in theory, version 1 is constantly recreating the component map, while version 2 only references a pre-defined value.

I tried recreating this by cutting protocols out:

```
(defn test-fn1 []
  req-comps)

(defn test-fn2 []
  {:position [0 0] :angle 0})

(time-multiple 1000000000
  (test-fn1))

(time-multiple 1000000000
  (test-fn2))
```

But this time, the results end up being almost identical: 3789.478675ms vs 3767.577814ms.

This leads me to believe it has something to do with protocols, but I can't tell what. What's going on here? I know that given the number of tests, 1000ms is fairly insignificant, so I'm not trying to micro-optimize here. I'm just curious.

```
(defmacro time-pure
  "Evaluates expr and returns the time it took.
  Modified the native time macro to return the time taken."
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (current-nano-timestamp)
         ret# ~expr]
     (/ (double (- (current-nano-timestamp) start#)) 1000000.0)))


(defmacro time-multiple
  "Times the expression multiple times, returning the total time taken, in ms"
  [times expr]
  `(time-pure
     (dotimes [n# ~times]
      ~expr)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case your map is a constant, created during class loading (it's statically known, so no new object creation during the method call.) On the other hand, your cached case costs you an extra indirection - accessing a var.

To demonstrate:

```
(def req-comps
   {:position [0 0] :angle 0})

(defn asystem-1 []
   {:position [0 0] :angle 0})

(defn asystem-2 []
   req-comps)
```

(It doesn't matter whether we deal with protocols or not - the functions are compiled the same, it's just easier to find them in the compiled code this way.)

```
public final class core$asystem_1 extends AFunction {
    public static final AFn const__4 = (AFn)RT.map(new Object[]{RT.keyword((String)null, "position"), Tuple.create(Long.valueOf(0L), Long.valueOf(0L)), RT.keyword((String)null, "angle"), Long.valueOf(0L)});

    public core$asystem_1() {
    }

    public static Object invokeStatic() {
        return const__4;
    }

    public Object invoke() {
        return invokeStatic();
    }
}
```

See - it just returns the precalculated constant.

```
public final class core$asystem_2 extends AFunction {
    public static final Var const__0 = (Var)RT.var("so.core", "req-comps");

    public core$asystem_2() {
    }

    public static Object invokeStatic() {
        return const__0.getRawRoot();
    }

    public Object invoke() {
        return invokeStatic();
    }
}
```

An extra call to `getRawRoot()`.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the second test disagree with the first though? I would expect them to agree if that were the case.

Comment: Because the results are so close (var access is very cheap) that the fluctuations in timing can get larger. And in case you have doubts I will show you the compiled code.

Comment: I think you're right, I'm still curious though why the difference is so much more prominent in the first test. I ran both tests multiple times, and the results were always the same (give or a hundred ms).

Comment: Microbenchmarks are dark art. JIT, whatever is happening around in the OS, almost the way the stars are aligned. 10-20% variance is nothing strange.